# Build a linux library for windows with MinGW

Tags: java, c++, linux, java-native-interface, mingw

There is a lib sources for linux with make scripts.
http://svn.gna.org/svn/pokersource/branches/poker-eval-java/.
I need to build it for windows. It should be two dll. The main dll and the second dll is jni-wrapper to call the native functions from java.
I have built it under the linux with such commands:

```
autoreconf --install
./configure --enable-java
make
```

It was built successfully and works fine. But now I need to make it for windows.
I've installed the MinGW with GUI installer and add mingw\bin to my PATH.
I run the same commands but have the error in make:

```
mv -f .deps/libpoker_eval_la-deck_std.Tpo .deps/libpoker_eval_la-deck_std.Plo
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../inclu
de -I../include  -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes  -g -O2 -MT libpoker_
eval_la-enumerate.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libpoker_eval_la-enumerate.Tpo -c -o libp
oker_eval_la-enumerate.lo `test -f 'enumerate.c' || echo './'`enumerate.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include -Wall -Wpoi
nter-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -g -O2 -MT libpoker_eval_la-enumerate.lo -MD -MP
-MF .deps/libpoker_eval_la-enumerate.Tpo -c enumerate.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .
libs/libpoker_eval_la-enumerate.o
enumerate.c: In function 'enumExhaustive':
enumerate.c:415:5: error: 'intptr_t' undeclared (first use in this function)
enumerate.c:415:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for ea
ch function it appears in
make[1]: *** [libpoker_eval_la-enumerate.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/drive/eval/lib'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Full console log is here
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12053587/mylog.txt

Could you help me to solve the problem?
Thanks

Comment: which mingw-g++ version are you using ?

Comment: How does this relate to Java?

Comment: it's a native lib with dll-wrapper for java - Java Native Interface. I can build it with cygwin for windows. But it doesn't work. causes the jvm crash.

Comment: how to find the mingw-g++ vesion?  $ gcc --version
gcc.exe (GCC) 4.5.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

in the enumerate.c file. This will get you past this error, but it's most likely you'll have to add this line to more than one file.

Comment: May be it can solve the problem. But I've built it at my Ubuntu without any changes and it works there correctly. Also I've built it with cygwin for windows. It was built without errors also. But the JVM always crashes when I use it from java on windows. Some people said there is something wrong with cygwin and they had the same problems with this lib on cygwin. But they built it with mingw and it works!

Comment: The `C++` standard does not specify which headers have to/must not be included by other standard headers. So most probably on Ubuntu, some other included standard header included `stdint.h`, while on windows it does not. So just manually include it.

Comment: @NullPointer There is a good chance that the configuration script isn't able to properly determine when/where it needs to '#include <stdint.h>' when executed from the mingw environment you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I add #include <stdint.h> and everything is fine!